# Use GET or POST to receive data from spring boot based on a list as a parameter axios?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, post, axios, get

I am trying to receive data based on a list with GET method but it is only working with POST method using axios. Here is the controller method

```
`    @RequestMapping("/test6")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> test6(@RequestBody List<String> shoppingList){
    System.out.println(shoppingList.size());
    System.out.println("From frontend: " + shoppingList.toString());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(shoppingList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
`
```

And here is the javascript method:

```
`const shoppingList2 = ["apple, ball"];  
  axios
.get("http://localhost:8081/test7?", shoppingList2)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
`
```

The error message I can see in the SPring boot app:

```
`2023-01-27T14:40:21.365+01:00  WARN 15488 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]        .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is   missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>   com.maremare.foodhunter.controller.TestController.test7(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)]`
```

The thing is when I change the axios from get to post everything is working fine. In other words, this is wokring fine:

```
  ` const shoppingList2 = ["apple, ball"];
   axios
   .post("http://localhost:8081/test6?", shoppingList2)
   .then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});`
```

I can use POST but the purpose of the API call is a GET request so I don't understand why the Get is not working.

When I change from get to post it is working fine

Comment: GET request can't send a request body. Use query params instead

Comment: But if I just use the post method instead for this solution, is it breaking any best practices, or would that be an ok solution?

Comment: @Konrad, is it wrong in the  javascript get request or the spring boot controller method?